# Alternative to Apache Tribes for Clustering of Axis2 Servers?

Tags: apache-axis, cluster-computing, wso2

Currently i am searching for possible Clustering technologies usable by Apache Axis2 servers. I know that WSO2 Platform uses Apache Tribes for their Servers which are based on Axis2? I want to know if there is an alternative to Apache Tribes for Clustering?

Comment: Here is a one https://code.google.com/p/pokura/

Answer (score 0):

We actually also tried JGroups .. but AFAIK, it did not workout very well.

Are you guys are hitting a problem with Tribes based implementation? Within WSO2 platform, tribes has worked out very well.

Comment: No, we did not have any problems with the tribes implementation. I was curious, whether you tried with other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

We are also looking into the possibility of writing a ZooKeeper based clustering implementation.